# Calculate $l=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{e^{\sin x}-e^{\tan x}}{e^{\sin 2x}-e^{\tan 2x}}$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, trigonometry

> Calculate $$l=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{e^{\sin x}-e^{\tan x}}{e^{\sin 2x}-e^{\tan 2x}}$$

What I have tried is to factor out $e^{\tan x}$ and $e^{\tan 2x}$ as well as a few other things, but they all lead me to $\frac{0}{0}$ which is not correct. So then, how would one solve this? What would be the first step? One place where I got to and seemed to be easier to go further from is $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin x - \tan x}{\sin 2x - \tan 2x}$ but I'm not quite sure what to do from here on. Hints are much appreciated!

Comment: You can use Taylor polynomial approximations.

Comment: Please ask concept not question this is not home work doing site, you should have search on the site before asking questions

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask (your question does *not* need to be "conceptual", and there does *not* seem to be an answer to your question on this site, but you are supposed to present your thoughts, efforts, attempts, in more detail than "I have tried some things which don't work, now I don't know what to do") Use Gary's hint + for any $c\ne0,$ $\lim_{x\to0}\frac{cx^3}{c(2x)^3}=\frac18.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Factoring out $e^{\tan x}$ does seem like a decent start.

$$ l = \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{e^{\sin x} - e^{\tan x}}{e^{\sin 2x} - e^{\tan 2x}} = \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{e^{\sin x - \tan x} - 1}{e^{\sin 2x-\tan x} - e^{\tan 2x - \tan x}}$$

Applying L'Hopital's rule,

$$ l = \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{e^{\sin x - \tan x}(\cos x - \sec^2 x)}{e^{\sin 2x - \tan x}(2 \cos 2x - \sec^2 x) - e^{\tan 2x - \tan x}(2 \sec^2 2x - \sec^2 x)} $$

if the above limit exists. Does this match what you had so far? Next, factor out the $\cos x - \sec^2 x$, since it's the part which still approaches $0$:

$$ l = \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{e^{\sin x - \tan x}}{e^{\sin 2x - \tan x}\frac{2 \cos 2x - \sec^2 x}{\cos x - \sec^2 x} - e^{\tan 2x - \tan x}\frac{2 \sec^2 2x - \sec^2 x}{\cos x - \sec^2 x}} $$

The $e^{f(x)}$ terms all approach $e^0 = 1$. So if you can find the limits of $\frac{2 \cos 2x-\sec^2 x}{\cos x-\sec^2 x}$ and $\frac{2\sec^2 2x-\sec^2 x}{\cos x-\sec^2 x}$, you're nearly there.

Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 1):

$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{e^{\sin x}-e^{\tan x}}{e^{\sin 2x}-e^{\tan 2x}}
=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{e^{\sin x}}{e^{\sin 2x}}\frac{e^{\tan x-\sin x}-1}{e^{\tan 2x-\sin 2x}-1}\\
=\lim_{x\to0}\dfrac{\tan x-\sin x}{\tan2x-\sin2x}
=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\tan x}{\tan2x}\dfrac{1-\cos x}{1-\cos2x}\\
=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{x}{2x}\frac{\frac12x^2}{\frac12(2x)^2}
=\frac{1}{8}.$$
Here we use: when $x\to0$, we have $e^x-1\sim x\sim\tan x,1-\cos x\sim\frac12x^2.$

Answer (score 0):

$$\lim_{x\to0}\dfrac{\sin x-\tan x}{\sin2x-\tan2x}$$

$$=\lim_{x\to0}\dfrac{\sin x\cos2x(\cos x-1)}{\sin2x\cos x(\cos2x-1)}$$

$$\begin{align}=\dfrac{\sin x\cos2x(\sin^2x)}{2\sin x\cos^2x(2\sin^2x)(1+\cos x)}\text{ } \end{align}$$  (multiplying the numerator & the denominator by $1+\cos x$)

$$=\dfrac{\cos0}{4\cos^20(1+\cos0)}=?$$ cancelling out $\sin x$ as $\sin x\ne0$ as $x\ne0$ as $x\to0$